# if and search function on power BI token literal expected

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table called "food suppliers" with a column called "sites" that have multiple countries ending in ".com", ".es", ".co.uk".

I want to create a new column that separates these sites into their corresponding country names using the if and search function on power query.

so far in power query custom column I have:

`Country =  IF (SEARCH ("*.com", foodsuppliers[sites],,0) = 0, IF (SEARCH ("*.es", foodsuppliers[sites],, 0)= 0, "Spain","UK"),"USA")`

But I am getting a "token literal expected" under the first = sign in "IF (SEARCH ("*.com", foodsuppliers[sites],,0) **=** 0"

does any one have ideas why or a better way to run this code on power query/power bi?

thanks.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in your code seems relevant

There is no SEARCH function, you want to use **Text.Contains**

You cant write **foodsuppliers[sites]** or you will be getting the entire column of all rows.  You probably want each current row, which you would get with **[sites]**

This is not excel where you can do =if (xxx,fff,zzz) the format is **if x then y else z**

I recommend some tutorials